# MVC 4 get 30 character from post title

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a blog and would like to get short text for the Post title

e.g `("This is original post title")`

`("This is orig....")`

My View Helper:

```
@helper Render(Post post, 
               System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, 
               bool isAdmin, bool showComments) 
{
    <div class="postTitle"> <a href="@Href("~/Posts/Details/" + post.ID)">
       <h1>@post.Title.Take(34)</h1></a><br /><br />
    </div>
```

But i get ``` System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d__3a``1[System.Char] ``` in the title position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Substring`

```
@post.Title.Substring(0, 34) + "...";
```

and must check the condition for the title have 34 characters .

**edit**: Must check the condition

```
@post.Title.Length >34 ?  @post.Title.Substring(0, 34) + "..." :  @post.Title;
```

Comment: Thank you so much , it worked after checking the title length

Answer (score 5):

If you need a bulletproof way to do it, use this [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static class StringExtensions {
    public static string TrimWithEllipses(this string s, int left) {
        if (s.Length < left)
            return s;
        else
            return s.Substring(0, left) + "...";
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
@post.Title.TrimWithEllipses(34);
```